# How can I customize the legend in ggplot2 in R for a line graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create my own legend such that I can minimalize the contents of the legend. Currently it looks like this.

[image]

Instead of the line type and colour appearing separately, how can I combine them. For example have the dashed line for Energy_M be in olive colour, and have the dashed line for food be in orange etc.

the is my ggplot code so far, I cannot figure out how to combine them, as each time I try to isolate either the line or the colour, it effect it's actual appearance in the graph:

```
ggplot(df7Q2, aes(x = REF_DATE)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Shelter_Growth_M, color = "Shelter_M", group = 1, linetype = "Shelter_M"), size = 1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Energy_Growth_M, color = "Energy_M", group = 1, linetype = "Energy_M"), size = 1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Food_Growth_M, color = "Food_M", group = 1, linetype = "Food_M"), size = 1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Shelter_Growth_Y, color = "Shelter_Y", group = 1, linetype = "Shelter_Y"), size = 1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Energy_Growth_Y, color = "Energy_Y", group = 1, linetype = "Energy_Y"), size = 1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Food_Growth_Y, color = "Food_Y", group = 1, linetype = "Food_Y"), size = 1.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Shelter_M" = "#26495c", "Energy_M" = "#c4a35a", "Food_M" = "#c66b3d", "Shelter_Y" = "#26495c", "Energy_Y" = "#c4a35a", "Food_Y" = "#c66b3d")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("Shelter_M" = "dashed", "Energy_M" = "dashed", "Food_M" = "dashed", "Shelter_Y" = "solid", "Energy_Y" = "solid", "Food_Y" = "solid")) +
  labs(title = "Month to Month and Year over Year comparison for CPI Growth of Shelter, Energy and Food",
       x = "Month",
       y = "Growth in Consumer Price Index") +
  scale_size(range = c(1, 2), guide = "none") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        legend.key.width = unit(2, "cm"))
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output from `dput(df7Q2)`.

Comment: Try passing `name = "Foo"` to both `scale_color_manual` and `scale_linetype_manual`, i.e. give both the same name.

Answer (score 1):

While simply assigning the same name to both the `color` and `linetype` legend as suggested by @joran would work to merge both legends, overall you could achieve your chart easier by reshaping your data to long format which allows to add your lines with just one `geom_line`.

Using some fake random example data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(123)

df7Q2 <- data.frame(
  REF_DATE = paste(
    c(month.abb[9:12], month.abb),
    c(rep(21, 4), rep(22, 12)),
    sep = "-"
  ),
  Shelter_Growth_M = runif(16),
  Energy_Growth_M = runif(16),
  Food_Growth_M = runif(16),
  Shelter_Growth_Y = runif(16),
  Energy_Growth_Y = runif(16),
  Food_Growth_Y = runif(16)
)
df7Q2$REF_DATE <- factor(df7Q2$REF_DATE, unique(df7Q2$REF_DATE))

# Reshape to long, create color and lty plattes
df7Q2 <- df7Q2 %>%
  pivot_longer(-REF_DATE)

pal_color <- c(
  Shelter_Growth_M = "#26495c", Energy_Growth_M = "#c4a35a",
  Food_Growth_M = "#c66b3d", Shelter_Growth_Y = "#26495c",
  Energy_Growth_Y = "#c4a35a", Food_Growth_Y = "#c66b3d"
)

pal_lty <- c(
  Shelter_Growth_M = "dashed", Energy_Growth_M = "dashed",
  Food_Growth_M = "dashed", Shelter_Growth_Y = "solid",
  Energy_Growth_Y = "solid", Food_Growth_Y = "solid"
)

ggplot(df7Q2, aes(x = REF_DATE)) +
  geom_line(aes(
    y = value, color = name, linetype = name,
    group = name
  ), size = 1.5) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = pal_color,
    labels = ~ gsub("_Growth", "", .x)
  ) +
  scale_linetype_manual(
    values = pal_lty,
    labels = ~ gsub("_Growth", "", .x)
  ) +
  labs(
    title = "Month to Month and Year over Year comparison for CPI Growth of Shelter, Energy and Food",
    x = "Month",
    y = "Growth in Consumer Price Index",
    color = NULL,
    lty = NULL
  ) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    legend.key.width = unit(2, "cm")
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you had not provided the data sample, I am looking at a tweak, which you might try and let me know if that works:

```
ggplot(df7Q2, aes(x = REF_DATE)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Shelter_Growth_M, color = "Shelter_M", linetype = "dashed"), size = 1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Energy_Growth_M, color = "Energy_M", linetype = "dashed"), size = 1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Food_Growth_M, color = "Food_M", linetype = "dashed"), size = 1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Shelter_Growth_Y, color = "Shelter_Y", linetype = "solid"), size = 1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Energy_Growth_Y, color = "Energy_Y", linetype = "solid"), size = 1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Food_Growth_Y, color = "Food_Y", linetype = "solid"), size = 1.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Shelter_M" = "#26495c", "Energy_M" = "#c4a35a", "Food_M" = "#c66b3d", "Shelter_Y" = "#26495c", "Energy_Y" = "#c4a35a", "Food_Y" = "#c66b3d"),
                     guide = guide_legend(title = "Variables")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("dashed", "solid"), 
                        guide = guide_legend(title = "Line Type")) +
  labs(title = "Month to Month and Year over Year comparison for CPI Growth of Shelter, Energy and Food",
       x = "Month",
       y = "Growth in Consumer Price Index") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        legend.key.width = unit(2, "cm"))
```

Here, the linetype and color aesthetic mappings are combined within the aes function for each geom_line call.